# What is wrong with my Which command syntax?

Tags: syntax

Here is an example of my issue:

```
condition=m>0;
f[m_] = Which[condition == True, 1, condition == False, 2]
f[-10]
```

returns

```
Which[(m > 0) == False, 2]
```

Why? I do not understand. What is even more odd is that flipping order inside "which", reverses where the problem occurs.

```
condition = m > 0;
f[m_] = Which[condition == False, 2, condition == True, 1];
f[-10]
```

returns

```
2
```

but the function now fails for say $f[10]$.

I know that I can fix the issue just by saying $m>0$ and $m<0$ but the conditions in my real code are much more complicated so I cannot do that. I must be making some syntax error. Thank you.

Comment: Lots of misunderstanding here ... Addressing all of them would take a long answer. It's best if you explain what you want to achieve and then someone can provide a solution. First, only use `==` for writing equations or testing numerical equality. See also `===`. Second, don't use `condition === True` and `condition === False`. Use `condition` and `Not[condition]`.

Comment: `f[m_] := 2 - Boole[m > 0]`

Comment: Since `Which` has the attribute `HoldAll`, it's best not to have the def. of `f` depend on external values. E.g. `f[m_] := With[{condition = m > 0},  Which[condition, 1, ! condition, 2]]`

Comment: I've seen `condition === False` before, and it can make sense if you cannot be sure `condition` has evaluated to `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do this as follows

```
ClearAll[m]
condition[m_] := m > 0;
f[m_] := Which[condition[m], 1, Not[condition[m]], 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Your `condition == False` is not right. And better to use functions for everything.

**Answer to comment**

If you do not want to use `:=` and want to use immediate assignment, then need to add `Evaluate`

```
condition = m > 0;
f[m_] = Which[Evaluate[condition == True], 1, Evaluate[condition == False], 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why is ``condition==False`` not right? I thought it tells if two things are equal. So if condition is False, they should be identical and hence should return True. No?

Comment: Also, why use ``SetDelayed`` for both definitions? Sorry for so many questions

Comment: @2132123 added note. The issue is evaluation, since you used immediate assignment. Better to stick to one method. I prefer delayed assignments for functions and to use functions for everything instead of having symbols just all over the place in global context.

Comment: Thank you very much for that addition. So just to be sure. The issue was that ``condition`` was held in unevaluated form? It is not ``-10>0==True`` but rather ``m>0==True``? I guess I thought assigning $m$ a value would influence all $m's$ inside the functions definition

Comment: @2132123 it has to do with evaluation. As noted above by Michale, Which has `HoldAll`. It is better as a general rule to use functions with delayed assignments and pass arguments into the function you want to work on these arguments. This will eliminate all these evaluation order issues.  If you use immediate assignment for function, then its body is evaluated at the time the definition is made, on whatever variable has values at the moment. Not when the function is called. So it is more safe to use `:=` (delayed) for functions unless there is specific reason not to do so.

Comment: would you happen to know any good guides where they describe how all of this works? It is very confusing. I thought immediate assignment say ``x=k`` means any instance of ``x`` is replaced by ``k``.  But testing it now I get different results then I expect. ``f[k_]=x`` is the identity function as I would hope. But ``f[k_]:=x`` just returns ``k``. Very confusing.

Comment: @2132123 have you read the documentation? You might also try asking a question about that, then others may direct you to a previous question or give an explanation that might help you.

Answer (score 4):

A better way to define that function is this:

```
f[m_]:=If[m>0,1,2]
```

or this:

```
f[m_]:=1+UnitStep[m]
```

However, if I was going to do that using Which, I would do this.

```
f[m_]:=Which[m>0,1,m<=0,2]
```

To understand the output of the original question consider evaluation of this code.

```
var=Sin[x];
g[x_]:={2x,3 var};
g[b+5]
(* {2 (5+b),3 Sin[x]} *)
```

When g[b+5] evaluates, (b+5) is used each place (x) appears on the right side of the definition of g[x_]. However that happens **before** {2 x, 3 var } evaluates. So the result is {2(b+5),3 var} and then var evaluates to Sin[x] but by then (x) is no longer associated with (b+5).

To develop effective programming habits in Mathematica, follow the style of those who write Mathematica books or learn from examples in the Wolfram documentation. For additional nuances related to the above example read [this.](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_19.html)

**** Update ****

Details of the evaluation process is in Chapter 7 of [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2dsyvptnxjd369/Wagner%20All%20Parts-RC.pdf) book, [this](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_3.html) web-page, and [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html) Mathematica documentation.

Comment: Very interesting. How do I know in what order Mathematica does thing? Is it in official documentation?

Comment: @2132123 I updated my answer to include links to the evaluation process.

Comment: See [`Operator Input Forms`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) Table of operator input forms, in order of decreasing precedence. Operators of equal precedence are grouped together.